# How does IFN A, 0x10 translate to 0xc00d in the original spec for DCPU 16

Tags: assembly, dcpu-16

I'm attempting to write an assembler for Notch's DCPU-16 spec.
The original spec for this CPU can be found [here](http://dcpu.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt).

The relevant lines:

```
SET A, 0x30 ;7c01 0030
```

...

```
IFN A, 0x10 ;c00d
```

I understand the instructions up to this point, but this one to me should be at least 2 words long rather than just `0xc00d`

```
SET A, 0x10
```

would be `7c01 0010`. so

```
IFN A, 0x10
```

should be `7c0d 0010` shouldn't it?

Why does the `b` argument in `IFN`, not cause the instruction to need a [PC++] or nextword component?

Comment: That is the old spec.  The new spec is [here](http://dcpu.com/highnerd/dcpu16.txt)

Comment: Thanks - I was aware of the new spec - but I started implementing it starting with the old one, in order to learn incrementally.

Comment: Link archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20120629091438/http://dcpu.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt

Comment: First link (from question and in my prior comment) is headed by ["DCPU-16 Specification \ Copyright 2012 Mojang \ Version 1.1 (Check 0x10c.com for updated versions)" (archived here)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120629091438/http://dcpu.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt), second link (from the comment by BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft) confusingly enough is headed by ["DCPU-16 Specification \ Copyright 1985 Mojang \ Version 1.1" (archived here)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120629091443/http://dcpu.com/highnerd/dcpu16.txt).

Comment: In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187712/reducing-size-of-switch-statement-in-emulator) I found a later revision of the specification, headed by ["DCPU-16 Specification \ Copyright 1985 Mojang \ Version 1.7"](http://pastebin.com/raw/Q4JvQvnM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     0x1f: next word (literal)
0x20-0x3f: literal value 0x00-0x1f (literal)
```

This is the core part of the spec you are asking about.  A literal value between 0 and 31 (0x1f) can be encoded in the opcode.  If the value is too large then the literal value needs an extra word, indicated with 0x1f.

So `IFN A, 0x10` needs only one word since the 0x10 literal is small enough to fit inside the opcode.  The 16-bit opcode breaks down in 6 bits for the b operand, 6 bits for the a operand and 4 bits for the instruction.  So b = 0x30 (0x20+literal), a = 0x00 (register A), instr = 0xd (IFN).  Put them together with `opcode = (b << 10) | (a << 4) | instr;` and you get 0xc00d.

Comment: with the new spec it's actually between -1 (0xFFFF) and 30 (0x1e)

Comment: Thanks Hans - that was actually explained in the spec I see now - doh.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Aye - I wanted to start with the original version and build up the assembler from there - It's mostly a learning exercise ;)